# when i fetch Admin name from list , it gives result as "[object Object]" and not the proper admin name

Tags: document-library, jquery

My List

Name



Age





DOB



Indian





Title



Admins





Doc Name



Doc Id

Address

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dept-dev.int.ally.com/sites/EA/Style%20Library/Scripts/Jquery/jquery.min.js" >
</script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.init.js"></script>
<script language="ecmascript" type="text/ecmascript">  
var collListItem;  
$(document).ready(function () {
try
{
    getSetListItem();
}
catch(e)
{
    alert("error occured at ready method" + e.message);
}
}); 


function getSetListItem() {  
   //var empID = $("input[title='Name']").val(); 
   var  qString = window.location.href.split("?ID=")[1];
   var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
   var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('My list');  
   var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();  
   camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/><Value Type=\'Numeric\'>'+ qString +'</Value></Eq></Where> </Query></View>');  
   collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);  
   clientContext.load(collListItem);  
   clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, OnLoadSuccess),  
   Function.createDelegate(this, OnLoadFailed));  
}  

function OnLoadSuccess(sender, args) {  
   var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();  
   while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {  
      var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();  
      $("#AgeId").val(oListItem.get_item("Age"))+ $("#NameId").val(oListItem.get_item("Name"))+$("#DOBId").val(oListItem.get_item("DOB"))+$("#IndianId").val(oListItem.get_item("Indian"))+$("#TitleId").val(oListItem.get_item("Title"))+ $("#AddressId").val(oListItem.get_item("Address"))+ $("#DocNameId").val(oListItem.get_item("DocName"))+$("#DocId").val(oListItem.get_item("DocId"));
$("#AdminsId").val(oListItem.get_item("Admins");
var value = SP.FieldLookupValue.get_lookupId(); 
SP.FieldLookupValue.set_lookupId(value);
   }  
}  

function OnLoadFailed(sender, args) {  
   alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());  
   }  



</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your "Admin" field is an user field, you can try `oListItem.get_item("Admins").get_lookupValue()`.

You can set a break point in browser and figure out the proper method to get this field value. The `get_item` method returns `[object Object]` when the field is not text, number, etc, for example, you use `get_url()` to get url of a hyperlink field, and use `get_label()` to get taxonomy field value.

Comment: I tired doing ur way also but it returns blank field and not admins name

Comment: @user52650 What does `oListItem.get_item("Admins")` return? Can you debug and see the details?